# Виртуальный манипулятор (джойстик) на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Для проекта требуется создать эмулятор джойстика, чтобы при определенном положении манипулятора серверу отсылалась определенная команда, исходя из X и Y координат.

[image: Серый квадрат в левом верхнем углу и есть сам манипулятор]

Серый квадрат в левом верхнем углу и есть сам манипулятор. Он должен находится в центре темно-серой области с начальными значениями X:0 Y:0

Передвижение осуществляется мышкой (навести -> нажать -> перетащить в любую точку области)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать? Так как в JS новичок, опыта совсем нет, погуглив понял, что используют фреймворк jQuery, но какие именно методы брать из него - не совсем понятно.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Joystick</title>
  <script src="joy.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="joyStick" class="joyStick">
    <div class="joyManipulator"></div>
  </div>

  <div id = "panel">
    <center>
    <p>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="ox" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="0" id="oy" /><br /></p>
    <button id = "reset">reset</button><p>
    </center>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

.joyStick {
    margin: 500px auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#222121; 
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    position:relative;
}

.joyManipulator {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:rgb(206, 206, 206);
    cursor:pointer;
}

#panel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #222121;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#reset {
    padding: 10px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Arial;
    border:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ox, #oy {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так как в JS новичок, опыта совсем нет

Необходимо изучить основы JS. Сделать такое можно при помощи getBoundingClientRect()

- https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates#koordinaty-otnositelno-okna-getboundingclientrect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Примеры реализаций:

- codepen.io/nathantaylor/pen/QdpOyB
- codepen.io/dev357/pen/ldaKx

Comment: спасибо за совет! вторая ссылка примера - прям то что нужно, буду изучать

Comment: Такие и подобные штуки начинайте сразу искать на codepen.io , codesandbox.io/search или tympanus.net/codrops

Тут можно найти готовые или полуготовые решения